# how to show minute picker after the user has picked hour in showTimePicker widget?

Tags: flutter

I want to immediately show minute picker to user after he has picked the hour with showTimePicker widget. how can I do that? here is my current code for showTimePicker:

```
final TimeOfDay timePicked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: selectedTime,
      );
      if (picked != null && timePicked != selectedTime) {
        setState(() {
          selectedTime = timePicked;

        });
      }
```

Comment: showTimePicker is used for both minute and hour picker, tapping on minute will show minute picker. i cant find a way to open picker with minute picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you can't do that in Flutter as of now. However, you can do it natively using `MethodChannel`.

You need to use `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`. [More info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog)